# Asynchrony loss function over an array of 1D signals

Tags: tensorflow, math, time-series, pytorch, loss-function

So I have an array of N 1D-signals (e.g. time series) with same number of samples per signal (all in equal resolution) and I want to define a differentiable loss function to penalize asynchrony among them and therefore be zero if all N 1D signals will be equal to each other. I've been searching the literature to find something but haven't had luck yet.

Few remarks:
1 - since N (number of signals) could be quite large I can not afford to calculate Mean squared loss between every single pair  which could grow combinatorialy large. also I'm not quite sure whether it would be optimal in any mathematical sense for the goal to achieve.

There are two naive loss functions that I could think of :
a) Total variation loss for each time sample across all signals (to force to reach ideally zero variation). the problem is here the weight needs to be very large to yield zero varion. masking any other loss term that is going to be added and also there is no inherent order among the N signals, which doesnt make it suitable to TV loss to begin with.

b) minimizing the sum of variance at each time point among all signals. however, choice of the reference of variance (aka mean) could be crucial I believe as just using the sample mean might not really yield the desired result, not quite sure.